# How do I use the TrackBall API in Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, user-input

I want to scroll up and down in a custom menu I have made using the trackball, but how do I receive and filter the trackball events? (I know how to process keyboard events using `protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time)`.)

Comment: i believe navigation click and navigation movement will do that work for track ball.which other events u want??

Comment: Navigation movement, I guess, maybe. But I just want events for when the user moves the trackball or trackwheel, since I do my own UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the navigationClick, navigationMovement and navigationUnclick methods in Field:

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#navigationMovement%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Or if you want to get the events before any of the fields do, override the same methods on the top-level Screen.

RIM strongly discourages the use of the old trackwheel API. Navigation is the way to go.